# Including part of .jsp file inside .html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jsp, jsp-tags

Is it possible to include a part of a .jsp file inside another .html.erb file?

If yes then how?

meanwhile the code I want to include is inside `<c:choose> .... </c:choose>`

I am trying translate a .jsp file functionality in ruby on rails .html.erb file. `<script>... </script>` part will be identical for both. How to add other parts as mentioned, in .html.erb

Answer (score 0):

You may call `jsp` and `erb` template files. They have "tags" that need to be interpreted by corresponding template engine/parser. As far as I know, there is no jsp template parser library written in Ruby yet. So, you can't just copy-paste JSP/JSTL tags to your ERB files.

However, you can "convert" them. For example, you can convert `<c:choose>` tag to Ruby's `case/when` syntax.

```
<% case some_var
     when 0 %> Option 0
  <% when 1 %> Option 1
  <% when 2 %> Option 2
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you plz tell me what will be the ruby equivalent of   <c: if test="${XYZ!  = null}" >

Comment: Careful with the spaces. It seems like you are trying to check `XYZ` for `null`. Ruby equivalent would be `if !XYZ.nil?` or `unless XYZ.nil?`.

Comment: that statement is inside the <c:choose> block so will it be like <% some_var  if .... %> ?

Comment: You can read all about it [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression).